# matlab like multiline plot in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

So I have a matrix of values were the rows correspond to sets of data, and I want to plot each of these using ListPlot but I want to have a different x-axis than the index. In matlab I would have:

```
x = 0:4;

ys = [10 20 40 80 160; 
      20 40 80 160 320; 
      30 60 120 240 480]';

plot(x,ys)
```

and this would give three lines with x-values 0-4 and the y-values being each column.

The closest I could come up with in Mathematica is

```
x = Range[0,4];

ys = {{10, 20, 40, 80, 160},
      {20, 40, 80, 160, 320},
      {30, 60, 120, 240, 480}};

ListPlot[Transpose[{x,#}]& /@ ys]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this the correct way? It seems a bit cryptic. Hoping there is a function or option I am missing.

Comment: One small item: you need not manually regroup those ys. Programatically one could do Partition[ys,Length[x]]. Likewise for Leonid Shifrin's DateRange one could use x[[{1,-1}]]. Nothing big, but these remove some of the manual work.

Comment: yeah the ys in my orginal problem came from a different calculation ... just wanted the code to be similar to the matlab :-) Thanks for the indexing trick on first and last though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your particular case, since the points are equidistant, you can use

```
ListPlot[ys, DataRange -> x[[{1,-1}]]]
```

Hope this is less cryptic. You can of course also use the range values directly:

```
ListPlot[ys, DataRange -> {0, 4}]
```

Comment: so great, DataRange is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: ok, I'll delete my comments (and then come back and get this one)